# Wordpress User/Group issue

Tags: wordpress, plesk

I used Plesk 12 to install Wordpress in an existing webspace, under the subdomain /new. Since the owner needed to still use some parts of the original site, I used PHP to redirect all domain calls to /new.  The site works fine, but plugin updates fail with the "The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files" error.  I have checked all file/directory permissions, and finally think it is a file ownership issue. Plesk expects files to be owned by the user of that account, and group set to psacln. Every Google article I find suggests that the group has to be something else, but they don't seem to take Plesk into account. The site is in shared hosting on a server I control. I keep thinking that Plesk is trying to load plugins to a default location, and is not aware of the actual location.

Can anyone suggest a work-around, or do I have to relocate Wordpress down one directory level? I don't want to install plugins manually. BTW, updating Wordpress itself works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to revert permissionos to default ones (644 for files):

```
 # find /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/new -type f | xargs chmod -R 644
```

Comment: The two lines after you're code include should be a comment since it is a question.

Answer (score 0):

First you should wich account is doing the copying. Then you should check specificly what contents need to be copied. Check those file permissions. For copying you need to have atleast read and write permissions.

In this case, since you've created the install with plesk, the user doing the copying is plesk. So check the file permissions of the account on the old and the new install. Maybe by, as told in a previous answer, Setting the permissions back to basic.

```
# find /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/new -type f | xargs chmod -R 644
```

If it doesn't help then i think you should step to manually once. Because once that you've placed the plug-ins manually you will not get the errors further more.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions led me to the answer. I believed that all the files were set to the proper ownership, but I didn't look deep enough; the directories under /plugins were not.  I fixed those, and it all works now.